# Issues with White and Blacklist entries in Snort

Tags: snort

Well, again, I was referring to [this guide.](http://www.symmetrixtech.com/articles/016-snortinstallguide2953.pdf) 
The problem was, after I have changed the values of

```
    var WHITE_LIST_PATH ../rules
    var BLACK_LIST_PATH ../rules
```

to:

```
    var WHITE_LIST_PATH /usr/local/snort/rules 
    var BLACK_LIST_PATH /usr/local/snort/rules
```

and I received the error message:

`WARNING: Can't find any whitelist/blacklist entries. Reputation Preprocessor disabled.`

so I then changed it to:

```
    #var WHITE_LIST_PATH /usr/local/snort/rules 
    #var BLACK_LIST_PATH /usr/local/snort/rules
```

but when I did that, I received a new error message:

`/usr/local/snort/etc/snort.conf(507) Undefined variable name: WHITE_LIST_PATH.`

Does anyone have any idea what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I re-downloaded the rules file from the Snort website, extracted it, copied it to the relevant directories and reconfigured the snort.conf file, and now Snort could run again.